# Do image recognition efforts always rely on machine learning and statistics?

Tags: machine-learning, image-processing

This is something I've always wondered.  Consider the Kinect.  It takes its 3d image data and manages to recognize that a human is contained at a given boundary.  Are these types of technologies exclusively machine-learning driven?

Comment: Machine learning as opposed to what? (I'm serious, not sarcastic here.) Without an alternative hypothesis, as it were, I think we'll end up following in the footsteps of other threads that ask for the difference between AI, machine learning, and pattern recognition (etc).

Comment: As opposed to say... methods in computational geometry.  Take for example the Medial Axis Transform.  Seems like an okay algorithm for extracting a human skeleton (even in 3d).  However, there are so many cases where it would fail (partial occlusions, camera only getting the top half of the body), that I'm not sure it's robust enough for real use.  This is just one example

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I don't have a good answer off the top of my head, but my initial guess would be that the algorithm's simpler than we'd like to think. Any good descriptions of what the Kinect is capable of? (I.e. how fine is its recognition and does it only recognize sweeping motions, as in looking for optical flow motion plus a pair of dark spots (eyes)?)

Comment: The Kinect gathers a full 3D depth map based off of an emitted pattern of infrared light (measuring how the light bends, basically).  It ends up with a complete "real-time" picture of the relative depth at each location in the camera-frame.  As for the algorithm for how it tracks the skeleton, I'm not sure which it uses :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, or at least I would say not necessarily explicitly. If you have an image formation model (e.g. derived from the physics of the imaging process), you can pose recognition, reconstruction or detection as an [inverse problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_problem) using [parametric](http://epubs.siam.org/siims/resource/1/sjisbi/v4/i2/p618_s1?isAuthorized=no) or [implicit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Level_set_method) representations of your "pattern" or object of interest without making any probabilistic modeling explicit.

For a more practical example, [backprojection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radon_transform) is a computationally efficient algorithm that solves the inverse radon transform and is often used to obtain tomographic pixel reconstructions (~ recognition of an image representing the object scanned). This is a situation where you have a well-posed inverse problem for a known forward model.

That said, many inverse problems [can be understood](http://iopscience.iop.org/0266-5611/18/4/201) as bayesian MAP or ML inference problems, where the forward model is re-written as a probabilistic model.

For example, if the inverse problem is ill-posed, it is common to use regularization methods (e.g. [TV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_variation) or [TR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tikhonov_regularization)) to make the numerical treatment easier. However, many regularizers can be understood in a bayesian sense as priors acting on the parameters that the inverse problem aims to recover.

Answer (score 1):

Amusingly, there are also some image recognition research efforts that do not rely on mechanistic identification - either by machine learning, statistics, or other automated methods. Instead, they contract the identification efforts out to human beings - who are fairly good at some forms of recognition, using a service like the Amazon Mechanical Turk.

Clearly, this approach won't work if you need real time image recognition, but it is an intriguing idea.

Answer (score 0):

Yes and No. Nothing is ideal. Uncertainties come from everywhere. There is no exact mathematical model for all. Even though there is, it takes long time to figure out. The easiest way is to fit into probabilistic models. Machine learning is the learning (training the parameters ) using statistics of the given samples.

Enes